# how to refresh combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

this is my sample codes..see the problems on how to refresh items in a combo box.

```
Private Sub cbo_payMO_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbo_payMO.SelectedIndexChanged<br>

   Select Case (cbo_payMO.Text)
        Case "JANUARY"
            cbo_payMO1.refresh() -- in case JANUARY I WANT TO REFRESH CBO_PAYMO1
                                                              to readd an items

        Case "FEBRUARY"
            cbo_payMO1.Items.Remove("JANUARY")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve using refresh?

Comment: i want to restore removed items...

Comment: there is no such thing as restore. you must have these items saved somewhere else or to know what exactly you do want to write in the combobox

Comment: problem solve sir. i remove then add new set of item :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.refresh()` call you have there isn't what you're looking for - you're wanting to clear out the ListItems and then add a new set, with different items.  I'd suggest maintaining a list or collection or array of some sort, separate from the `.Items` of that combo box.  Then you need to call `.Items.Clear()` followed by `.Items.AddRange(SomeListOfStuff)`